# Failed to start lightdm (stuck on bootloop)

Tags: kubuntu, lightdm, boot-repair, display-manager, sddm

Currently I was using kde on ubuntu. But after trying to install cinnamon and lightdm, I can't start my OS. It is stucked on boot logo. And it's showing, "failed to start lightdm". I tried to go to terminal using ctrl+alt+f3 but I can't go to terminal.
Is there any way to change display manager by editing any configuration file?

Comment: Can you access recovery mode or are you able to boot after setting the nomodeset parameter ( you can look up in the net for this )?
Maybe [Kubuntu Stuck at Boot Logo](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/66151-Kubuntu-stuck-on-boot-logo) and [(SOLVED) Stuck at boot logo - lightdm failed to start](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=144932) be of some help to you, you can post further results by editing the question if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: the display-manager is stored in `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` with full path. Example  `/usr/bin/sddm`